# Date.parse javascript for the August error

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime

When I use Javascript `Date.parse` for a date in August, I always get the first. This only happens for the month of August.

```
alert(Date.parse("20 Aug 2014"));  // give me Sat Sep 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
alert(Date.parse("20 Aug 2014"));  // gives me Fri Aug 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse("20 Aug 2014"))` returns `Wed Aug 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` for me in Chrome.

Comment: `Date.parse("20 Aug 2014")` returns a timestamp number, not a date.

Comment: `console.log(Date.parse("20 Aug 2014"));` returns `1408510800000` and `console.log(Date.parse("20 Aug 2014"));` right after returns `1408510800000`. I think the comments in your code are incorrect.

Comment: my suggestion is use `moment.js`

Answer (score 1):

`Date.parse` is not documented as accepting a string in that format, so you cannot rely on it doing so.

[`Date.parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) (and the version of [`new Date`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3) that accepts a string) are only required to support these formats of strings:

- Whatever `Date#toString` outputs (but the spec doesn't dictate what that is)
- As of the 5th edition spec, a [simplified *(and slightly incorrect*)* ISO-8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

In my experience, all implementations also support the American `mm/dd/yyyy` format (even in non-US locales), but that is *not* specified or documented behavior.

If your input string is in that format, you'll have to parse it yourself or use a library like MomentJS to do it for you.

---

Side note: In your code, you said that `Date.parse` was giving you a `Date` (or a date string; you said the alert was showing "Sat Sep 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)" and the like). That would be fairly surprising. `Date.parse` returns a *number*, not a `Date`. To get the equivalent `Date` object, use `new Date`.

---

* About *"(and slightly incorrect)*": In ISO-8601, a string with no timezone indicator on it defines a time in *local* time. ES5, however, says those are GMT.